# Save all information from a range and restore it later

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to assign a font to a range?

Let's say I have an object myFont. I can write:

```
 with Range("A1").Font
       .Bold=myFont.Bold
       .Size=myFont.Size
       same with other properties
end with
```

but there are a lot of font properties. Is there a way to do something like
 Range("A1").Font=myFont?

Comment: No, the font property of the Range object is read only.

Comment: Not tested but how about using `Font.FontStyle`?

Comment: Toris, FontStyle only has Bold and Italic information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one-liner to do what you want.  One possible shortcut below, but you're really still iterating over each property...

```
Dim p, myFont, rng As Range

'populate myFont, rng

For Each p In Array("Bold", "Color", "Size") 'for example
    CallByName rng.Font, p, VbLet, CallByName(myFont, p, VbGet)
Next p
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font properties, follow the code below. Specifically, to change Range("A1") font name, use "Font.Name" as shown below.

To get this, I simply recorded a Macro of me changing the font and then stopping the Macro to view the code. Try recording Macros to find the property you need at times. Hope this helps.

```
Sub ChangeFontCustomRange()

' Change Font Name

    'Select the Range to change font to
    Range("A1").Select

    'Change font properties, specifically, Font.Name
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri" 'Type exact font name here
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub
```